# How do I correct this For Each loop in java (incorrect output on final test)?

Tags: java, foreach

I'm struggling to run this java correctly with a `for each` loop. It is fine for every test but the last. Could anyone kindly assist in letting me know where I'm going wrong? I feel confident I could do it with a `for` loop but would like to do it with a `for each` loop (if suitable).

Drill Question:
Given an array of ints, return true if the sequence of numbers 1, 2, 3 appears in the array somewhere.

```
arrayOneTwoThree([1, 1, 2, 3, 1])  -> true. 

arrayOneTwoThree([1, 1, 2, 4, 1])  -> false. 

arrayOneTwoThree([1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3])  -> true.
```

For example:

```
int[] array = {2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1};

System.out.println(arrayOneTwoThree(array));
```

Result: **true**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //int[] array = {2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1};
    //int[] array = {1, 1, 2, 3, 1};
    //int[] array = {1, 1, 2, 4, 1};
    int[] array = {1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3};
    System.out.println(arrayOneTwoThree(array));
}

public static boolean arrayOneTwoThree(int[] nums) {
    for (int num : nums) {
        //System.out.print(num);
        if (nums[num] == 3 && nums[num-1] == 2 && nums[num-2] == 1)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: For what input does your code fail?

Comment: I would use a traditional for loop for(int i = 2; i < nums.length; i++) { ... }. You need to do this to access the index. You want to start at two because you're accessing nums[i - 1] and nums[i - 2].

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava the array passed in the example (int[] array = {1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3};) does not return the desired result but the others all do ( //int[] array = {2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1}; int[] array = {1, 1, 2, 3, 1}; int[] array = {1, 1, 2, 4, 1};). I'd really love to know why, maybe something to do with the condition being met on the final index?

Answer (score 1):

In the loop, num is NOT the index within the array, it is the value.

I think you are expecting num to  be the index, which would be the case if you did a for loop of the form `for (int num =0; num < nums.length; num++)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare n adiacent elements of array you have to use a loop ending to length - n - 1 : in your case n = 3 so your method can be written like below:

```
private static boolean arrayOneTwoThree(int[] array) {
    final int n = array.length;
    if (n < 3) { return false; } //<-- for arrays with less than 3 elements
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; ++i) {
        if (array[i] == 1 && array[i + 1] == 2 && array[i + 2] == 3) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First tree test cases **accidentally** shoved correct result!

Your code works ONLY for cases, **when index of 1 is 1, index of 2 is 2, and index of 3 is 3**:

```
[*, 1, 2, 3, ......... ]
```

You are probably confused with another programming language. (Maybe *for in* construction of JavaScript?).

In Java *for each* over array (or anything else) iterates over values and never over indexes. (As was already specified)

I can see commented out `System.out.print(num);` why you've ignored it prints values not indexes?

Another issue is ignoring array bounds... Try to examine your code with next array:

```
int[] array = {2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3};
```

It'll end up with `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

**And answer for your question, how to solve with *for each*.**
Yes, you can introduce external counter, but what would be the sense then?

```
public static boolean arrayOneTwoThree(int[] nums) {
    int i = 0;
    for (int num : nums) {
        //System.out.print(num);
        if (i < 2) continue; // we do not want ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException happened, right?
        if (nums[i] == 3 && nums[num-1] == 2 && nums[num-2] == 1)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you wish to use *for each* you should avoid of using indexes to be consistent.
There could be tons of different solutions. You can use some flags or save previous and beforePrevious:

```
    public static boolean arrayOneTwoThree(int[] nums) {
        int beforePrevious;
        int previous = 0;
        int current = 0;
        for (int num : nums) {
            //System.out.print(num);
            beforePrevious = previous;
            previous = current;
            current = num;
            if (current == 3 && previous == 2 && beforePrevious == 1)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Beware: It's just first thought, so this solution may be not optimal and far from perfect, probably you can do better.